# FTP get and delete multiple files

Tags: ftp

I have to get and delete multiple files via FTP so I wrote this script:

`open ftp.myftpserver.org
user
pass
cd folder
lcd E:\localdir
mget *
mdel *
bye`

This works but is not safe since the `folder` is being fed from other sources and the `mdel *` step may delete files uploaded in the meanwhile.

I guess a solution could be moving the files remotely to a different folder, building a filelist at the beginning of the process, but i have no idea how to make it.

Is it possibile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FTR I followed the nice hint and I managed to succesfully made something working, maybe not elegant but works:

**First step to get the file list:**

getfilelist.bat

```
    open ftp.myserver.it
    myuser
    pass1234
    cd ftpfolder
    prompt n
    lcd E:\localdir
    ls *.??? filelist.txt
    bye
```

**Second step to download and delete the above files**

movefiles.bat

```
    @echo off

    setlocal enableextensions
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    echo open ftp.myserver.it>>myscript
    echo user myuser pass1234>>myscript
    echo cd ftpfolder>>myscript
    echo prompt n>>myscript
    echo ascii>>myscript
    echo lcd E:\downloaddir>>myscript
    for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2* delims=," %%G IN ("E:\localdir\filelist.txt") DO ECHO rename %%G %%G_TMP>>myscript
    echo mget *_TMP>>myscript
    echo mdelete *_TMP>>myscript
    echo bye>>myscript
    ftp -n -s:myscript
    del filelist.txt
    del myscript
    e:
    cd E:\downloaddir
    ren *.???_TMP *.???
```

**A bat file to recall the above steps:**

```
    E:
    cd E:\localdir
    ftp -i -s:E:\localdir\getfilelist.bat
    E:\localdir\movefiles.bat
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. It looks a lot of people struggle here ;-)

I have to download multiple files and remove them after successfully downloading them on the remote Server to avoid double processing. There is a very small chance that while doing an `mget` the remote System adds further files. So a `mdelete` might delete untransferred files.

My approach was not to use anything else than FTP commands. Here we go:

```
cd <dir on remote server>
mkdir Transfer
mv *.* Transfer
mget Transfer\*.*
del Transfer\*.*
rmdir Transfer
```

At a glance I move all files to an extra directory on the remote server. Should be very fast as this happens locally. Once the files are shifted to the transfer dir, I perform the real `mget` download. This might take longer and meanwhile further files can be safely uploaded on the remote Server main dir.

After the download is done, I delete all files in the transfer dir and remove the dir itself.

Comment: smart but not 100% safe

Comment: @ciquta. Could you elaborate why this is not 100% safe ?

Comment: Anyway, not possible with Windows built-in FTP client. mv command doesn't exist and the existing rename command doesn't accept *

Comment: @abillon It is not safe when script run more than once in parallel for example. Solution is to use random string as part of name of the Transfer folder.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you can do that with a script from with ftp client.

Might be better to do it as a program or scipt using a language of your choice with an FTP library so you have much more control of the FTP operations. e.g. perl with Net::ftp, java etc.

You could then implement a algorithum like:

```
remote cd to required folder
localcd to required folder 
list current files in remote folder
for each file in list that matchs required pattern
   get file
   if get ok then 
      delete file
   else
      log error,exit or whatever error handling you want
   endif
endfor
```

Also need to make sure you don't try to get a file that is in the process of being written, depending on o/s this might be handled for you with file locks, but you need to make sure files are written to the remote dir in a two stage process. First too a temporay directory or file name that does not match the file pattern you are checking for, then renamed or moved into the correct location and name that you will detect.

Comment: Thanks, but I have no possibility to run program, i can use dos command line at best.

Answer (score 0):

ok, then i think you can implement the algorithum i've described as a batch script using two seperate ftp calls and scripts. The first to list the files to be transfered from the remote dir, the second to get and delete a single file from the list.

The file get script would have to be created dynamically on each loop iteration to get the next file.

```
cd to working dir
Run FTP with script to: 
     cd to remote folder
     list files matching required pattern and store in local file
       (e.g: ls files_*.txt filelist.txt)

for each file in file list created above (e.g. use 'for /f ...' command to loop through filelist.txt)
   create temp ftp script to:
       cd to remote dir
       lcd to local dir
       get file
       del file
   run FTP with temp script
endfor
```

This site has an example of doing similer (note script as shown dosn't work, comments give details of corrections needed).

http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/batch-ftp-script-list-rename-get-delete/25728.html